Endogeneity in cross sectional data
As someone new to econometrics, I am currently facing challenges in constructing a theoretically persuasive model to identify causal effects.
My interest is whether agricultural labor demand in household i (X1) affects children's work in domestic agricultural work (Y).
My hypothesis is, in case educational opportunity cost is high, child is likely to engage in the domestic agricultural work.
Another potential determinant is the household income level (X2), which may influence children's agricultural labor.
The data is cross-sectional.
Each observation is corresponding to an individual child in household i. I processed the secondary data to create this. The original data is Thailand Vietnam Socio Economic Panel (TVSEP), available for all if requested.
Given that both X1 and X2 are endogenous and I have yet to find suitable instrumental variables, could we discuss strategies for establishing causality between X1 and Y?
Furthermore, in my understanding,  propensity score matching may not be suitable as X1 is a continuous variable.
Also alternative solutions to model my stated problem would be very welcome.
P.S.
TVSEP data is panel, but information on labor demand is only available from the second latest dataset collected in 2017. The most recent survey was conducted in 2022. Since 2022 coincided with the COVID-19 pandemic, which could have affected children's working status, I have chosen not to use it for constructing panel data. This is why I am using 2017 data as cross-sectional instead.
